# How do I set an image form a database using ruby to feature in the background of a div in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

This is the code I have I want the image to fill the background of the Thumbnail. typically i would set the background image in CSS but as the image is coming from the Database i'm not 100% what to do.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
           <% if property.gallery.photos.size > 0 %>
            <%= image_tag property.gallery.featured.image_url%>
           <% end %>
       </a>
    </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add your class in the CSS tag like so:

```
 <%= image_tag property.gallery.featured.image_url, css: "your class names" %>
```